# Gradient descent methods

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, descent

$f(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2+yz+z^2-4x-8y-8z-1.$

Can we use gradient methods to determine the minimum of $f(x, y)$? 
What's the most interesting gradient methods can be used to determine the minimum of $f(x, y)$?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x,y,\color{red}{z})$, finding the minimum of this function of three variables?

Comment: You should check if your function is convex/concave to decide (just check if the quadratic form is positive/negative definite.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use gradient methods to determine the minimum of $f (x, y, \color{red}{z} )$?

Yes, you can use the gradient.

The function is differentiable and will attain extreme values (minima or maxima) in its stationary points: these are the points for which all partial derivatives are zero, i.e. when the gradient is (equal to the) zero (vector).

So compute 
$$\nabla f=\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)$$
for
$$f(x,y,z)=x^2+xy+y^2+yz+z^2-4x-8y-8z-1$$
and then solve $\nabla f = (0,0,0)$.

This will be a system of three linear equations in three unknowns ($x,y,z$).

Comment: Yeah exactly, but there are many gradient's methods. In this function which one is the best to use? and thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what different (kinds of) methods you're referring to.

Comment: step size fixed-step size optimal-conjugate gradient method

Comment: I'm not familiar with those but they sound like they're numerical methods - feel free to use them but you can solve this problem analytically ("exact") with the method above.